# TFS generate report like VSS for source control

Tags: version-control, tfs

In [VSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe), it was possible to generate a complete list of the files that were children of the current folder. This could be accomplished by selecting `Tools` -> `Files Report`, which could be output to a printer, file or clipboard.

Does similar functionality exist in [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) for a list of source control files(**not** work items, bugs, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First start Visual Studio Command prompt. Change folder to your source folder. Then write this:

```
tf.exe dir -r
```

You can read more about tf.exe on MSDN here: [Tf Command-Line Utility Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)