# How to list files in SourceGear Vault

Tags: version-control, report, sourcegear-vault

How can I generate a report that represents all the files in a hierarchical manner using SourceGear Vault?

I know [VSS and TFS have this functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12956133/299327), and I am hoping that Vault does as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the command line:

`vault LISTFOLDER top_of_your_repository > status_report.txt`

*From the command line helps:*

> LISTFOLDER usage: vault.exe LISTFOLDER [options] repositoryfolder
>
> LISTFOLDER will display the contents of the folder specified by
>   repositoryfolder, including the status of any working folders.
>
> Server and authentication information is specified by:
>   **-host** host Hostname of the server to connect to. Can also use "-server".
>   **-ssl**  Enables SSL for server connection.
>   **-user** username Username to use when connecting to server.
>   **-password** password Password to use when connecting to server.
>   **-repository** repositoryname Repository to connect to. This is a list of possible options:
>   **-norecursive**  Do not act recursively on folders.